# LED on button push ATMEGA328p

Tags: led, button, atmega328p

I am using a Tinkerkit button as input to Arduino PORTD pin0 and expect an output on PORTC, pin0 as output.

Code:

```
void wait_for_button()
{

  if( (PORTD & (1<<PD0)) )
      PORTC|=(1<<PC0);
  else
      PORTC|=~(1<<PC0);

}
int main (void)
{

  DDRD=0x00;   //PORTD pin 0 as input
  PORTD=0x00;
  DDRC=0xFF;   //PORTC as output
  PORTC=0x00;

   while(1)
   {
     _delay_ms(200);
     wait_for_button();
   }
```

}

HW Setup:
http://ibb.co/ek6R7a

TinkerKit:
http://www.mouser.com/catalog/specsheets/TinkerKitPushButton.pdf

LED does not lightup on button push. what am i doing wrong?

Comment: have you confirmed your hardware setup by running the example code given in your TinkerKit link?

Comment: 1st thing you're doing wrong is not including all of the relevant detail in the body of your question.

Comment: @brhans What exactly is not detailed? Its pretty straight forward right?

Comment: All I see is a bunch of links I'm not clicking on.

Comment: @Makoto That example Arduino program seems to work fine!

Comment: Your line "PORTC|=~(1<<PC0);" should probably be "PORTC&=~(1<<PC0);" instead.

Comment: Nope, still does not work

Comment: I tried doing the HW setup same as in the Tinkerkit example  ie. PB3 as output and PC0 as input, still does not work, seems to be a SW problem

Comment: Are your push button is connected between pind.0 and GND?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in the code that detects a button press. You wrote:

```
if( (PORTD & (1<<PD0)) )
```

However, you should write this instead:

```
if(PIND & (1 << PD0))
```

This is because `PORTD` is the output register. It will only reflect values that you write to the pin, not an external voltage. `PIND` is the input register, which reflects the voltage read at the pin.

And as brhans pointed out, `PORTC |= ~(1 << PC0);` should be `PORTC &= ~(1 << PC0);` instead.

Comment: Thanks, I did not know that! That did it!

Comment: I am glad I could help. I hope you have successful tinkering!

Comment: Yea sure! So if i understood correctly PINx is mainly used to enquire the state of relevant PIN (1 or 0) , while using peripheral like ADC it is irrelevant, right?

Comment: Yes. `PINx` is regular register, so it can only hold 1 or 0. Thus, there is a particular cut-off voltage (I think around 3V), above which `PINx` will hold a 1, otherwise a 0. The ADC is the only way to get a higher voltage resolution.

Answer (score 1):

As I am new to stackexchange I have to write an answer.

Some things I would do:

1. Check that no internal pull-ups on the input pins are activated.
2. Measure the button output voltage when it is pressed.
3. Use a debugger to check the register states when button is pressed or released.
4. Make sure that UART is not enabled on the "arduino" RX pin.

Comment: He ensured that internal pull-ups are not enabled by writing a 0 to both `DDRD` and `PORTD`.

Comment: My answer was more of a general nature. I wasn't particulary thinking about how the AVR ISA works. But thanks, I will try to make my answers more concrete for the architecture being used.